# Only show a portion of a live Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, embed, google-sites

I want to embed a live Google Sheet inside of new google sites. works fine but I want to hide/remove the title row and column headers and just show the workspace area

I have tried the following iframe code ( below )  in New Google sites and it still displays titles, row and column headers

Could you tell me what I am missing?

```
<iframe width="100%" height="400" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_id/edit?usp=sharing&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
```

I have published to the web and used HTML embed parameters, however, HTML versions of the sheet take too long to update or it's unpredictable. The data is updated by a Google form.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="400" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_id/edit?usp=sharing&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
```

Sheet displays in its entirety.  I can hide some elements in the app but rows and column headers remain.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: <iframe id="pip" width = 100% height="700" seamless frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/____________________#gid=0#headers=false#chrome=false"></iframe>

Comment: for ref think this is section i want to display  -   <div class="goog-inline-block grid4-inner-container" style="width: 922px; height: 349px;">

Answer (score 0):

use `&range=A3:C10` parameter in URL like:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B56.../pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&gid=0&range=A3:C10" width="400" height="350"></iframe>
```

this will publish only the range **A3:C10**

Comment: thanks for the answers .  but  HTML versions of the sheet take too long to update or it's unpredictable..  so ive had to move back to embedding the live sheet . on the live embed ive managed to get rid of menus by using rm=demo parameter but rows and column headers remain .